# Error connecting to database: (using class net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pentaho-data-integration

I have used Pentaho 8.2 community edition in CentOs operating system. The SnowFlake driver version used is 3.9.2. But when we try to fetch data from ktr using Pentaho it gives below-mentioned error. Please help.

```
An error occurred, processing will be stopped:
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
Error connecting to database: (using class net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver)
JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Failed to find the root CA..
2019/11/27 03:34:18 - TI_XREF_SHIPS_LEADS_SALES_FILE.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [TI_XREF_SHIPS_LEADS_SALES_FILE]
```

I also installed certificate with below command and restarted pentaho server. still the same erroe.
`java InstallCert ******.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443`

Java Version used

```
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This is a pretty generic error. "communication error" could mean a few things... Without the troubleshooting steps that you've already tried it's hard to suggest a good starting point, other than generic "try reinstalling it" "did you check your connection string" etc.

Comment: The Snowflake team is pretty responsive to issues like this though. If your initial troubleshooting isn't working, I'd suggest writing down everything you've tried and messaging them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not able to reach certificate issuer. Before you installed the cert, was it exactly the same error signature or different at the end? Remove the cert as this step is not required at all.

Go through the diagnostics tool at the link below:

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowcd.html#snowcd-connectivity-diagnostic-tool

Also if you are using Fail-Open mode, then go through the links below:

1. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ocsp.html#fail-open-or-fail-close-behavior
2. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ocsp.html#verifying-communication-with-your-ca-site-or-ocsp-responder